# TSQL - Illegal xml character

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that returns XML.
It is for a survey application.

It loops through all of the questions and choices for the survey and returns the XML.

However, whenever I try to include the question text in the XML I get an illegal xml character error.

I am looking at all of the questions, and there are no special characters, in fact the only not alpha character is the period at the end of the questions.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Here is my query:

```
SET @root = (SELECT
    CONVERT
        (xml, 
            (
                SELECT   q.QuestionId '@questionId'
                        ,q.DisplayOrder '@orderId'
                        ,q.IsRequired '@required'
                        ,q.Weight '@weight'
                        ,CONVERT(xml, 
                                    (
                                        SELECT       
                                            qc.QuestionId '@questionId'
                                           ,qc.DisplayOrder '@orderId'
                                          ,(SELECT REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(qc.[Description] ,'&','&amp;')),'''','&apos;')),'"','&quot;')),'<','&lt;')),'>','&gt;'))
                                        FROM    survey.Question qc
                                        WHERE  qc.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
                                        FOR XML PATH ('question')
                                    )
                        )
                        ,CONVERT(xml, 
                                    (
                                        SELECT       
                                            qc.QuestionChoiceId '@choiceId'
                                            ,qc.DisplayOrder '@orderId'
                                            ,qc.Weight '@weight'
                                            ,ISNULL(qc.Description,'') '@description'
                                        FROM    survey.QuestionChoice qc
                                        WHERE  qc.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
                                        FOR XML PATH ('choice'), type, root('choices')
                                    )
                        )

                FROM    survey.Question q
                WHERE  q.SectionId = @SectionId
                FOR XML PATH('questionset')
            )
        ))
```

If I replace my "sanitization" select statement, and replace with hardcoded text, my query works fine.

Here is some sample questions from the DB.

Any additional comments or suggestions are appreciated:

The classier
   was courteous and professional.

The classier provided good reasons
   for their assessments.

Comment: We could really do with some sample data that triggers the problem. And you shouldn't need to perform any manual entity replacement.

Comment: Why should I not perform entity replacement? Is this handled automatically?   See updated question for sample data.

Comment: yes, the tools take care of XML escaping requirements - e.g. run `select 'A & B' as [@fido] for xml path, root('def')` and examine the output. And by sample data I was hoping for a complete script creating some table structures (table variables can usually work) and inserts. Preferably, on a *reduced* set of columns (and then with a *reduced* query) that's just enough to demonstrate the same error - e.g. a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the TYPE directive as the following script.

```
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
```

Answer (score -1):

Those (SELECT REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE((... statements are not needed. Just use nested REPLACE functions like:

```
(REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE(qc.[Description] ,'&','&amp;')),'''','&apos;')),'"','&quot;')),'<','&lt;')),'>','&gt;'))
```

or with less parentheses:

```
(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([FileName] ,'&','&amp;'),'''','&apos;'),'"','&quot;'),'<','&lt;'),'>','&gt;'))
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? It looks like you are just shortening my replace statement. Is this correct?

Comment: @GordonBell - in what way do you believe that they're "not valid"? `select replace((select replace('abc','b','g')),'c','f')` executes just fine and produces the string `agf`. It's not as pretty as it could be but is a long way away from not working.

Comment: OK, not invalid, but multiple useless subqueries.

Comment: It's far from not pretty, it introduces multiple nested loops in the query plan.